# For hyperparameter tuning with cross validation, is it okay for the fold splits to be same for every hyperparameter trial?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-evaluation

For hyperparameter tuning (random search/ grid search/ bayesian optimization), there are many trials performed for each set of hyperparameters. To evaluate how good a set of hyperparameter is, we can use k fold cross validation which splits the training data into k folds.

Previously, I used to split the training data into k fold and used the same fold splits for all my hyperparameter trials. However, after trying out sklearn Pipelines, it seems that using a pipeline with RandomsearchCV results in a different k fold split for each hyperparameter trial.

I am wondering if it matters at all if we used the same k fold split for all trials or if it is important that we randomized the split for each trial?

Comment: If your concern is random stability, then use the [`RandomizedSearchCV(..., random_state)` parameter](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html). *"it seems that using it results in a different k fold split..."* depends on what seed you used.

Answer (score 6):

It'd actually be better to use the same folds while comparing different models, as you've done initially. If you input the pipeline object into the randomCV object, it should use the same folds. But, if you do the other way around, each run will change the folds as you said. Even in that case, you can fix the folds by fixing the `cv` argument in the pipeline object.

Comment: Oh true, I remember seeing code examples that pass the CV object. One question though, if I pass a cv argument for example, cv=5, it will use the same 5 fold splits. But if my pipeline has a preprocessing step before the model, will the preprocessing part of the pipeline be "re-run" for every trial? If so, isn't this quite wasteful...

Comment: Are you inputting your pipeline into RandomCV object or is RandomCV object a step in your pipeline? The first one is a better design.

Comment: @LimKaizhuo you can use the `memory` option of `Pipeline` to cache the preprocessing steps on each fold.

Comment: @gunes It is the first, e.g. regr = make_pipeline(preprocess, regr)  followed by  RandomsearchCV(regr, params)

Comment: Yes, it'd be repeated but you can follow @BenReiniger's advice on that.

Comment: @BenReiniger Oh the memory parameter is perfect! I will read up into it, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Using the same or different splits amounts to using a different experimental design for your optimization:

Using the same splits means that you are setting up the comparisons for your optimization in a paired fashion. Paired tests/comparisons typically have higher statistical power which you may use for your optimization decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping same fold for hyperparameter tunning is better idea. If you have random data in each iteration, then you will not be able to understand whether variance in the model is coming due to random data or different hyperparameter.
So, to eliminate variance in the model due to randomness in the data, we generally use static folds which can be created before grid or random search starts.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first rephrase the question to make it a little more precise:

"I am wondering if it matters at all if we used the same k fold split
for all trials or if it is important that we randomized the split for
each trial?"

Assume you perform hyperparameter tuning using fixed folds, and random
folds. The two tunings will select, in general, different models as
the best. The split method matters if those two models have
significantly different performance. Conversely, if the difference in
performance is negligible, the choice of fixed or random folds does
not matter, because they both select equally good models. I'll set
aside for the moment on how you decide if the two selected models are
different (not trivial, but it's a separate topic).

To my knowledge there is virtually no literature published on your
question. I have used both methods, and have not noticed difference in
performance, but have not explored the question systematically. But if
the choice of random vs. fixed folds had a significant effect, there
would have been published reports about it. My answer is, therefore,
in practical sense it doesn't make a difference which method you use

To be sure, cross-validation *can* produce heavily biased performance
estimates for small sample sizes, but neither fixed nor random CV can
solve the problem in such datasets. It can be alleviated, to a degree,
using repeated CV and nested CV:

https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1758-2946-6-10